# Is it possible to get the incremental var of my for inside my callback ? Javascript + GoogleMap API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the shorter way between an origin point and a station among some station. For that, I use the service DistanceMatrix of googleMaps Api. I would like to make "stationNameArray[i].distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;" inside the callback because I have no bind between the station test and the result of the test due to the fact that the request is asynchronous. Someone has an idea ?

```
findShorterWay = function(){
    var tmpStationArray = [];
    origin = document.getElementById('shorterWays').value;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    if(origin){
        for (var i = 0; i < stationNameArray.length; i++){
            var destination = {lat: stationNameArray[i].lat, lng: stationNameArray[i].lng};
            var request = {
              origins: [origin],
              destinations: [destination],
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
              avoidHighways: false,
              avoidTolls: false
            };
            service.getDistanceMatrix(request,function(response,status){
                 if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    // I would like to do here "stationNameArray[i].distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;"
                     var adress = response.destinationAddresses[0];
                     var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                     tmpStationArray.push({adress:adress,distance:distance});
                     if (tmpStationArray.length === stationNameArray.length){
                        var min =findMin(tmpStationArray);
                        itinerateMe( origin ,tmpStationArray[min].adress);
                     }
                 }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Self-Executing Anonymous Function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) to achieve this:

```
findShorterWay = function(){
    var tmpStationArray = [];
    origin = document.getElementById('shorterWays').value;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    if (origin) {
        for (var i = 0; i < stationNameArray.length; i++) {
            var destination = {lat: stationNameArray[i].lat, lng: stationNameArray[i].lng};
            var request = {
                origins: [origin],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            };
            service.getDistanceMatrix(request, (function(i) { // this function takes an input parameter i
                // return a new function with locally scoped i
                return function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                        // the value of i locally scoped (not from the loop variable)
                        stationNameArray[i].distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                        var adress = response.destinationAddresses[0];
                        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                        tmpStationArray.push({adress:adress,distance:distance});
                        if (tmpStationArray.length === stationNameArray.length) {
                            var min =findMin(tmpStationArray);
                            itinerateMe(origin, tmpStationArray[min].adress);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })(i)); // pass the loop variable to the function
        }
    }
}
```

This issue that you are running into is that by the time that the callback is made, the local variable `i` has been incremented.  You can create a scoped copy of `i` by passing it into a function which will overwrite the meaning in the callback.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I got the same idea but it doesn't works too. I don't know why, normaly with this approach the distance calculated is bind with his station, but when I call the function, values changes every time...

Comment: My bad, it's works too, I did a bad moove. Thank you